# Is there a way to get the name/email of a person from the digital signature in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to extract the name and the email of a person from the Digital Signature?

[image]

Comment: I tried to get this working, but the `$PSBoundParameters` was always null, if you figure this out can you post an answer, thanks. https://sysadmins.lv/blog-en/retrieve-timestamp-attribute-from-digital-signature.aspx

Comment: I guess you can use the code mentioned by @JeremyThompson. Capture the output in a variable and parse the X500DistinghuishedName formatted `SignerCertificate.Subject` string. Something like `$IssuerName = if ($result.SignerCertificate.Subject -match 'O=([^,]+)') { $matches[1] } elseif ($result.SingnerCertificate.Subject -match 'CN=([^,]+)')  { $matches[1] }` and for the email address: `if ($result.SignerCertificate.Subject -match 'E=([^,]+)') { $matches[1] }`